# Angular JS - How to make form validation as global service? Best practice

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

I have a few forms with data validation in my Angular app.
All forms contains same validation messages like this:

```
 <span class="formValidationError" ng-show="myForm.customViewName.$error.required">Required!</span><br>
                    <span class="formValidationError" ng-show="myForm.customViewName.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
                    <span class="formValidationError" ng-show="myForm.customViewName.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
                    <span class="formValidationSuccess" ng-show="myForm.$valid">Data valid</span>
```

I would like to make my forms much easier for maintenance.

Is possible to make this validation message as globals service, directive, or something similar?

**My forms looks like this one:**

```
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add name of custom view</h4>
            </div>
            <form name="myForm">
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" name="customViewName" ng-model="customView.name" class="form-control" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" required>
                    <span class="formValidationError" ng-show="myForm.customViewName.$error.required">Required!</span><br>
                    <span class="formValidationError" ng-show="myForm.customViewName.$error.minlength">Too short!</span>
                    <span class="formValidationError" ng-show="myForm.customViewName.$error.maxlength">Too long!</span>
                    <span class="formValidationSuccess" ng-show="myForm.$valid">Data valid</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" ng-controller="UsersCtrl" ng-disabled="!myForm.$valid" ng-click="saveCustomView()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Could please somebody recommend some good solution for this?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: All fields has the same message and validation functionality? It is time to use **directives** and close same functionality into it.

Answer (score 2):

The question might be old but you should definitely take a look at my [Angular-Validation Directive/Service](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation). I was tired to repeating code over and over with the way AngularJS suggested us. So I decided to build my own library for validation.

It has so many features and is so easy to use you will laugh. Taking your example, you would simply take your input and add a new attribute of

`<input ... validation="min_length:5|max_length:10|required" />`

and you're done! The library takes care of the rest, there's over 50 validator types available and they all have a defined generic error messages (also available in 7 different locale languages). You can also easily define custom regular expression pattern if the default validators aren't enough.

So you can't be more simple than that... 1 line of code, or should I say, add 1 new attribute inside your input and voila!!!

Let's give a bigger example, using default AngularJS way of validating a form is like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8" required />
<div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.user.$touched">
  <span ng-show="userForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
  <span ng-show="userForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
</div>
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="50" required />
<div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.user.$touched">
  <span ng-show="userForm.firstname.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Firstname is too short.</p>
  <span ng-show="userForm.firstname.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Firstname is too long.</p>
</div>
<input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="50" required />
<div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.user.$touched">
  <span ng-show="userForm.lastname.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Lastname is too short.</p>
  <span ng-show="userForm.lastname.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Lastname is too long.</p>
</div>
```

with my `Angular-Validation` it's as easy as:

```
<input type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" validation="min_len:3|max_len:8|required"  />
<input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" validation="alpha_dash|min_len:3|max_len:50|required"  />
<input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" validation="alpha_dash|min_len:2|max_len:50|required"  />
```

3 inputs = 3 lines of code. That is the way it should be and the way it should stay. Simplicity is the key.

Available on both `Bower` and `NuGet` (under the tag name of `angular-validation-ghiscoding`). So please take a look at my library [Angular-Validation](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation) and a live demo on <kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/jADq7H)</kbd>.

It's loaded with features (custom Regex validators, AJAX remote validation, validation summary, alternate text errors, validation on the fly with the Service, etc...). So make sure to check the [Wiki Documentation](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-validation/wiki) as well... and finally, it's fully tested with Protractor (over 1500 assertions), so don't be afraid of using in production.

Please note that I am the author of this library

Answer (score 1):

From our side we had a similar issue and we decided to implement ValidationSummary directive:

http://lemoncode.github.io/lc-validation-summary/

https://github.com/Lemoncode/lc-validation-summary

Using this approach you can centralize all your error messages in a single entry point (e.g. configuring them in a given provider). It is pending to implement a SingleFieldSummary directive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a directive I wrote for this task. Take a look how I use it:

```
<input type="text" name="customViewName" ng-model="customView.name" class="form-control" ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="10" required="" />
<div validate-error="customViewName">
    <span class="required">Required!</span>
    <span class="minlength">Too short!</span>
    <span class="maxlength">Too long!</span>
</div>
```

And this is the code of the directive:

```
angular.module('directives.validation', []).directive('validateError', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AM',
        require: '^form',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, formController) {

            function validate() {

                if (formController.$dirty) {

                    $formGroup.toggleClass('has-error', ngModelController.$invalid);

                    if (showErrorMessages) {
                        var errors = element[0].children;
                        if (errors.length > 1) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                                angular.element(errors[i]).toggle(ngModelController.$error[errors[i].className]);
                            }
                        }
                        element.toggle(ngModelController.$invalid);
                    }
                }
            }

            /** @property validateError */
            var $formGroup = element.closest('.form-group'),
                showErrorMessages = element[0].nodeType === 1,
                ngModelController = formController[attrs.validateError];

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return ngModelController.$error;
            }, validate, true);

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return formController.$pristine;
            }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    validate();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

All the errors are initially hidden with this CSS:

```
[validate-error] {
    display: none;
    color: #A94442;
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/dLvBUGH2Q4peddbizxqV?p=preview